# Last 3 dates for a given primary key ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, select

I'm trying to select the last three records for a given TICKET based on MAINT_DATE. This is using queries/tables in MS Access. Below is what I have right now to sort out any duplicates. However, I can't figure out the rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Example - select only the ones the last 3 (Note: I would want to keep all the other fields as well)

```
Ticket  MaintDate
100     2/2/2014 
100     2/3/2014 <
100     2/4/2014 <
100     2/5/2014 <
101     2/2/2014
101     2/3/2014 <
101     2/4/2014 <
101     2/5/2014 <

SELECT DISTINCT 
    NAME, 
    TICKET, <-- Primary Key
    TITLE, 
    STATUS, 
    RESOLUTION_DATE, 
    DAYS_OLD, 
    MAINT_DATE, 
    PROGRESS_NOTE
FROM 
    PNT_Primary
WHERE 
    STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
ORDER BY 
    NewName, TICKET, MAINT_DATE;
```

Thank you very much for any help...

Comment: What RDBMS you are using ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *given* ticket, you can use:

```
SELECT TOP 3 NAME, TICKET, <-- Primary Key
       TITLE, STATUS, RESOLUTION_DATE, DAYS_OLD, MAINT_DATE, PROGRESS_NOTE
FROM PNT_Primary
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' and TICKET = XXX
ORDER BY  MAINT_DATE DESC;
```

However, if `TICKET` is the primary key, as suggested by the question, then there will be no duplicate values.

If you want the last three for all tickets, that is harder.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT NAME, TICKET, <-- Primary Key
       TITLE, STATUS, RESOLUTION_DATE, DAYS_OLD, MAINT_DATE, PROGRESS_NOTE
FROM PNT_Primary p
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' and
      3 >= (select count(*)
            from PNT_Primary p2
            where p2.ticket = p.ticket and p2.status = 'ACTIVE' and
                  pt2.main_date >= p.maint_date
           )
ORDER BY  MAINT_DATE DESC;
```

The subquery in the `where` clause counts the number of records that have a larger or equal value of `MAINT_DATE`.

Comment: Touched it up a little bit and it works like a charm. Appreciate it!

SELECT NewName, TICKET, TITLE, STATUS, RESOLUTION_DATE, DAYS_OLD, MAINT_DATE, PROGRESS_NOTE
FROM progressnoteTracker_Primary p
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' and
      3 >= (select count(*)
            from progressnoteTracker_Primary p2
            where p2.ticket = p.ticket and p2.status = 'ACTIVE' and
                  p2.MAINT_DATE >= p.MAINT_DATE
           )
ORDER BY  NewName, TICKET, MAINT_DATE DESC;